# EWS Pull Notification problem with unread mails arrived between polling intervals

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

EWS Pull notifications are great in fetching new mails arriving while polling for the notifications, however if I increase the intervals between polling requests, the mails arriving between each requests do not get picked up.
Am I doing something wrong, or missing something trivial?

Comment: Figured it out, I wasn't retaining watermark for each hop. Now its working with retaining the watermark from previous run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retaining previous watermark solvEd it

Answer (score 2):

```
String subscriptionID = null
do {
  PullSubscription subscription = service.subscribeToPullNotifications (...subscriptionID ...) 
  subscriptionID = subscription.getWaterMark();
  ...

} while(true);
```